# Density of $C_0(X)$ in $L^2(X)$

Tags: measure-theory, lp-spaces

Let $X$ be a locally compact space and $m$ be a $\sigma$ finite measure on $X$. Consider $C_0(X)$. Let $f \in C_0(X)$ and $g \in L^2(X)$. Then can I conclude that $fg\in L^2$? Or do we need any more assumption for $m$?

Also is $C_0(X)$ dense in $L^2$?

Comment: $f$ is bounded so $fg \in L^{2}$.

Comment: is it always bounded for any measure?

Comment: Boundedness of functions in $C_0(X)$ has nothing to do with the measure. It is a topological fact.

Comment: is $C_0(X)$ dense in $L^2$?

Comment: That requires regularity of $m$.

Comment: Thank you so much